# How can I make shredded beef?

Tags: beef, mexican-cuisine, cut-of-meat

In Australia, shredded beef is not something you can buy easily. I haven't seen it anywhere except in restaurants.

I would like to know how I can make my own restaurant quality shredded beef; the same kind that appears in "Mexican" restaurants. Please also provide information on which cut of beef I should be using along with the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Chuck to make your shredded beef. Cook it for a long time, at a low temperature, until a probe slides in and out of it with no resistance. Braising in a liquid seasoned with spices like cumin, garlic, and chili powder will get you the flavor profile you want (I recommend either finding a recipe or some trial and error).

Comment: I'd also suggest brisket, which breaks down into nice tender strands

Comment: @Sean - Thanks for your answer. How do I do the 'shredding' part once I get the meat soft? I tried once, but it ended up more like mince.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 If you've cooked it long enough, you should be able to pull it apart with two forks, no cutting involved.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: You can also just use your fingers.

Comment: @jefromi- the problem with using your fingers is that you have to let it cool and then you end up eating it all one sneaky bite at a time.

Comment: What @Yamikuronue said.

Comment: I was recently introduced to pork adobo, and it has become my current cooking obsession. The method is just as described here, only with soy sauce and vinegar in the braise.

Answer (score 1):

using a crockpot is the easiest way.  take beef brisket (around 2 pounds for 4 servings) and submerge in liquid in the crockpot.  either use beef stock, seasoned water, or my favorite- beer.  cook on low for 8-9 hours.  remove the brisket from the crockpot and put on a cutting board.  take two forks-using one to hold the brisket down, the other to pull at the brisket.  work along the striations in the beer, and you should get pulled or shredded beef.  put the now pulled beef into a bowl and ladle some of the cooking juices onto the beef to keep it moist.  if you want to add hot sauce or bbq sauce at this time you can.

before adding to the crockpot, make sure to trim some of the larger fat junks off of the brisket.  makes for pulling the beef later much easier.

Comment: When I put it in the crockpot it overcooks even on low. I have a temperature controlled cooker but I have no idea what temp is best.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a pressure cooker.  Use a roast or some cheap cut of beef (or pork), cut it in chunks and pressure cook it for 10-15 minutes.  Then, use two forks to pull it apart.  If it is done enough, it falls apart and makes wonderful shredded beef.  Flavorings can be added after that initial cooking.